# ¿Podría traducirse el "Q" y "A" por "P" y "R" para designar preguntas y respuestas en el perfil de usuario?

Tags: bug, estado-completado, traducciones, interfaz-de-usuario

Cuando [buscamos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hola), los resultados muestran una "P" delante de las preguntas y una "R" delante de las respuestas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, en la [página de perfil](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/83/fedorqui?tab=profile) aparece "Q" para preguntas (de *Q*uestion) y "A" para respuestas (de *A*nswer).

Además, "Preguntas" aparece con mayúscula inicial, mientras que "respuestas" no. Yo apostaría por equilibrarlo poniendo la "R" mayúscula en "respuestas".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Reportado inicialmente como [respuesta a ¿Qué textos hay que no han sido traducidos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2662/83)

Comment: Esto podría considerarse como parte de "Los Cambios de Diseño" de la graduación del sitio :-) La imagen a modificar está **[acá](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/user-profile-sprite.svg)**

Comment: @Pikoh ¿podéis revisar las sugerencias de cadenas para solucionar lo que comenta Pollo en comentarios a mi respuesta? [`^Q:`](https://es.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=%5EQ%3A)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' hecho. Cualquier cosa de estas avísame dado que no entro tan a menudo como debería a traducir :)

Comment: @Pikoh gracias! Hace días que quería comentarte distintas cosas, pero es que soy alérgico al chat. Dejo los títulos por si algún día hay tiempo: asociación de preguntas yo voy añadiendo pero ir haciendo ping a Nicolas me resulta tedioso. También repasé muchas etiquetas de [main] y allí están las propuestas en forma de preguntas en Meta para cuando los moderadores (tú, vaya :D) le echéis un ojo y queráis implementar. Pero creo que para estar en modo 'SO deja de dañar' le estoy haciendo demasiado trabajo a SE que no acabo de sentirme cómodo haciendo y por el que no veo que la gente tenga interés

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' te aseguro que al menos yo valoro inmensamente el trabajo que realizas para la comunidad. Y te entiendo, yo tambien me siento a veces asi y de hecho he tenido dudas sobre seguir como moderador, pero creo que no es el momento de dejarlo. En cuanto a tus sugerencias de unir etiquetas, las he visto, pero mi tiempo tambien es limitado y no puedo llegar a todo la verdad. De todas maneras te animo y tienes mi apoyo total para seguir con tu labor, no por la empresa sino por la comunidad :)

Comment: @Pikoh gracias a ti por tu labor. Por el momento pararé mi actividad en etiquetas y demás.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que esto [se implementó](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355415/209901) al hilo de la pregunta en Meta.SE [Allow localizing the "Q" and "A" icons in the user profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347163/209901) que lo ha implementado para SOru, SOpt y SOes:

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis, en lugar de "Q" y "A" para pregunta y respuesta, ahora sale "P" y "R".

Comment: Excelente!!! Una consulta: en los resultados de búsqueda veo que aparecen bien, excepto las [preguntas duplicadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3Ayes), que aún retienen la "Q"... Espero que no sea una pifiada, quizás sea que ya se implementó la internacionalización, y simplemente falta traducirlo. Sin embargo no sabría cómo revisarlo. ¿Alguna idea de esto?

Comment: @Pollo buena observación! Esto es que se olvidaron de este caso. Sería cuestión de comentarlo en la respuesta de MetaSE que enlazo o bien crear una pregunta nueva al respecto. Es raro...

Comment: Recién se me ocurrió... mirar en el sitio ruso: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=duplicate%3Ayes donde se ve que está bien. Entonces entiendo que tiene que estar bien la parte del backend, y únicamente falta traducirlo

Comment: @Pollo reportado en [Duplicate questions in search page do not have “P” and use English's “Q” for SOes and SOpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355546/209901)

Comment: Para más información, pueden seguir esta respuesta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347163/allow-localizing-the-q-and-a-icons-in-the-user-profile/355415#355415

Comment: Gracias, @JuanM, añadí en mi respuesta referencia a la resolución allí explicada.